# How to read character until a char character?

Tags: c, input, char, infinite-loop

I'm trying to do a loop that read from a file a single character until it finds `'\n'` or `'*'`.

This is the loop that I wrote:

```c
i=0;
do { 
      fscanf(fin,"%c",&word[i]);
      i++;
    } while(word[i]!='*'&&word[i]!='\n');
```

Now I tried to see why it doesn't work with a debugger. When I print `word[i]` immediately after the `fscanf` it shows me the correct character but then, if I try to print `word[i]` while it's doing the comparison with `'*'` or `'\n'` it shows me that `word[i]` is `'\000'` and the loop never ends.

I also tried with `fgetc` but I have the same error.

Comment: It looks to me like the `i++` means that the `i` in `fscanf(fin,"%c",&word[i])` does not have the same value as the `i` in `while(word[i]!='*'&&word[i]!='\n')`.

Comment: I didn't realise that, I put an if clause inside the loop and now it works thank you

Comment: You should also add a condition for checking that you do not exceed the length of word array.

Comment: print `i` in the debugger too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that the character you are processing is the same you just read.

Actually you increment counter `i` before testing word [i], that's why your check fails.

Try instead

```
i=0;
do { 
      fscanf(fin,"%c",&word[i]);
    }while(word[i]!='*'&&word[i++]!='\n');
```

I would rather move the check in the loop (break if the condition is satisfied) leaving in the while check the test on word array length.

Comment: Should there be an `&& (i < word.length)` before the `&&word[i++]!='\n'`, as [suggested by Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59011511/how-to-read-character-until-a-char-character#comment104271167_59011511)? (I don't know C for the length of an array.)

Comment: @Andrew Morton. I agree and I've written it. But I just provided the code according to the known information (word.lenght sounds like a c++ feature, and thi is C)

Comment: Apparently it would be best if the OP used the length they had set the array to. (For the OP's reference: [How do I determine the size of my array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37538/1115360).)

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
for(;;) {
   int c = fgetc(fin);
   if ( c == EOF ) {
      break;
   word[i] = c;
   if( c == '*' || c == '\n' ) {
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: +1 for a way that doesn't involve any spurious assignments; one might need `i` to do more stuff, (like terminating the string.)

Comment: My example is only part of what is needed. It also needs to ensure that word[] is not over-indexed. It should add the terminating NUL only if it is really supposed to be a String, and not just an array of chars.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` condition is not testing the same element of `word` that you just read, because `i++` incremented the variable before the test.

Change the test to use `word[i-1]` instead of `word[i]` to adjust for this.

BTW, `word[i] = fgetc(fin);` is a simpler way to read one character.